# Sublime Text on OSX: Spell checker does not learn

Tags: macos, latex, sublimetext2, spell-checking

I'm trying to get the/a spell checker working for ST2 on OSX (10.6.8 and 10.8.5). The build-in solution does a pretty good job, especially for LaTeX files. I do see words underlined in red, if ST2 thinks they contain a typo. But if I choose to "ignore" these words (no more highlighting then) and restart Sublime Text, they're highlighted again (same thing happens with ST3).

I'm not even able to find the list of ignored words and I somehow get the impression that ST seems to "forget" those words. I've tried to add a list manually in my Preference.sublime-settings file: no effect.

The "CheckBounce" plugin looks like a promising alternative, although LaTeX support is missing (most commands are highlighted as incorrect).

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You should consider editing the "Any more alternatives out there?" at the end of your question, since it makes the question sound like you are asking for a tool recommendation, something that is off-topic here (see [#5 under the off-topic section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in help), and you do have a good question in the middle there.

Comment: In addition to @lawlist's answer, you can manually add words to your dictionary: Just edit `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Language - English` and add the words in question.

Comment: @Derek: Thanks, I've removed the last part.

Comment: @AGS: I've edited the en_US.dic file, just adding the words I'd like to "ignore" (or rather "learn") but they are still highlighted as incorrect.. what am I missing here?

Comment: @damarus, probably a restart, I'd imagine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the section for `ignored_words` below.  You need to *manually* add words to your preferences file.  I've set the preferences files to hot-keys to have easy access.

/Users/HOME/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings

```
{
    "auto_complete_triggers":
    [
        {
            "characters": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?",
            "selector": "text.shtml"
        }
    ],
    "color_scheme": "Packages/User/lawlist.tmTheme",
    "find_selected_text": false,
    "font_face": "Courier",
    "font_size": 18.0,
    "forward_sync": true,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "ignored_words":
    [
        "Joinder",
        "\\bf\\uline",
        "\\begin{singlespace*}",
        "\\end{singlespace*}",
        "\\begin{tightcenter}",
        "\\end{tightcenter}",
        "\\begin{document}",
        "\\end{document}",
        "quotingsetup",
        "renewenvironment",
        "doublespace",
        "flushright",
        "minipage",
        "pagestyle",
        "uuline",
        "textbf"
    ],
    "inverse_cursor_state": true,
    "keep_focus": false,
    "scroll_past_end": true,
    "show_full_path": true,
    "word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?"
}
```

Comment: Adding "ignored_words" as suggested does not work for me.. I've copied your list to my preference file and added "Joinder" to my tex file: still highlighted as typo. ST seems to ignore this list (and I cannot add words via the context menu either as described above). Restart of ST and/or reload of the file does not help..

Comment: This works for Sublime Text 2 version 2.0.1 on OSX 10.6.8.  The check-bounce plugin should be disabled; and, the path to your theme file would be different than mine.  It sounds like you may have a problem with your installation.  Try backing up everything to a different location, and reinstalling.

Comment: Ha! Interesting.. I started from scratch (removed the Library files) with a new installation of ST 2.0.2 on OSX 10.6.8, added a list of ignored words and after a restart, these words are no longer highlighted! Awesome, thank you for that! The thing is, I cannot ignore words from the context menu plus I need to restart ST2 each time I add a new word manually.. any ideas on that?

Comment: Unfortunately, that would require writing a plugin that modifies the settings profile file and re-initializes Sublime Text 2 -- similar to what happens when disabling or enabling a plugin with package control (which inserts or removes the name of the package being disabled / enabled).

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying that. But is this behavior the default one? Seems to be a bit confusing and cumbersome..

Comment: Yes, it is the default behavior, and yes, I agree.  I wanted more control so I've spent hundreds of hours learning how to customize Emacs (with email, and Toodledo calendar sync), but I still enjoy using Sublime Text 2 to modify the Emacs configuration files.  I may someday switch over completely to Emacs, but I still find Sublime Text 2 very useful since edits to the Emacs configuration files often break its useability until my edits get debugged.  Emacs can use Aspell, which provides the feature you seek.  Aquamacs uses the native built-in spell checker and the user custom `LocalDictionary`.

Comment: If you haven't noticed already, the native built-in spell checker for Sublime Text 2 on OSX sporadically flickers colors for the misspelled words and there is no known fix -- I had to switch to a white background so the words didn't disappear completely -- now they just flicker green.

Comment: Actually, adding words in the preference files works fine for ST3 - you just need to restart it

Comment: The issue of persistence was fixed in Build 3080 (released: 24 March 2015)

Answer (score 5):

It seems like the `ignore_word` command in your sublime does not add the word to the `ignored_words` list. I am currently using ST3 and it has the same problem. So I made a small plugin to make the context command `ignore xxxxx` adds a word to the `ignored_words` list in your user's `preferences.sublime-settings`.

Here is the repository: https://github.com/zcold/ignore_words

- If you are using package control, just add a new repository and install the plugin named `ignore_words`.
- If you do not use package control, just create a `ignore_words` folder in `${sublime}\data\packages\` and copy the file `ignoreword.py` from the mentioned repository into that folder.

I hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this, is add the word by hand to the dictionary.
Locate the .dic file, in there you will see a big list of words with the follow format `word/p [CAT=,G=,N=]` 
 Those things after the word are features of the word (e.g proper name ,feminine,...) 
 Find a similar word and copy that part to your entry.
 Save the file, restart your editor (to reload the dictionary) and you should be good to go :)